What I am doing wrong in the code while i try to search in recyclerview?
I am using Firestore to fetch data. I have implemented Search option in my recycler view. In the first instance recyclerview fetched data but the moment i click on search my data row from vanishes. Even does not come when i exit from search. Don't know What i am doing wrong?
Adapter Code is....
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.studentViewHolder>implements Filterable
{
ArrayList<ModelViewStudent> datalist;
ArrayList<ModelViewStudent> backup;

public StudentAdapter(ArrayList<ModelViewStudent> datalist) {

    this.datalist = datalist;
    backup=new ArrayList<>(datalist);
    //backup.addAll(datalist);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public studentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
     return new studentViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull studentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.t1.setText(datalist.get(position).getName());
    holder.t2.setText(datalist.get(position).getClassName());
    holder.t3.setText(datalist.get(position).getAdNum());

    holder.t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(holder.t1.getContext(),StudentDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("uid",datalist.get(position).getUid());
            intent.putExtra("residence",datalist.get(position).getResidence());
            intent.putExtra("phone",datalist.get(position).getPhone());
            intent.putExtra("AdNum",datalist.get(position).getAdNum());
            intent.putExtra("name",datalist.get(position).getName());
            intent.putExtra("mothername",datalist.get(position).getMothername());
            intent.putExtra("fathername",datalist.get(position).getFathername());
            intent.putExtra("dob",datalist.get(position).getDob());
            intent.putExtra("admdate",datalist.get(position).getAdmdate());
            intent.putExtra("RollNumber",datalist.get(position).getRollNumber());
            intent.putExtra("AdNum",datalist.get(position).getAdNum());

            intent.putExtra("className",datalist.get(position).getClassName());






            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            holder.t1.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datalist.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return filter;
}
Filter filter=new Filter() {
    @Override
    //background thread
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence keyword)
    {
       ArrayList<ModelViewStudent>filtereddata=new ArrayList<>();
       if(keyword.toString().isEmpty())
           filtereddata.addAll(backup);
       else
           {
           for(ModelViewStudent obj:backup)
           {
               if(obj.getName().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toString().toLowerCase())){
                   filtereddata.add(obj);

               }

           }
       }
            FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
       results.values=filtereddata;
       return results;
    }

    @Override
    //manin thread
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        datalist.clear();
        datalist.addAll((Collection<? extends ModelViewStudent>) results.values);
        //datalist.addAll((ArrayList<ModelViewStudent>) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};

class studentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView t1,t2,t3;

    public studentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        t1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameV);
        t2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.classV);
        t3=itemView.findViewById(R.id.adNumV);

    }
}

}
And code for Model Class is ..
public class ModelViewStudent {
String AdNum,RollNumber,admdate,className,dob,fathername,gender,mothername,name,phone,residence,uid;
public ModelViewStudent() {
}

public ModelViewStudent(String adNum, String rollNumber, String admdate, String className, String dob, String fathername, String gender, String mothername, String name, String phone, String residence, String uid) {
    AdNum = adNum;
    RollNumber = rollNumber;
    this.admdate = admdate;
    this.className = className;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.fathername = fathername;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.mothername = mothername;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.residence = residence;
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getAdNum() {
    return AdNum;
}

public void setAdNum(String adNum) {
    AdNum = adNum;
}

public String getRollNumber() {
    return RollNumber;
}

public void setRollNumber(String rollNumber) {
    RollNumber = rollNumber;
}

public String getAdmdate() {
    return admdate;
}

public void setAdmdate(String admdate) {
    this.admdate = admdate;
}

public String getClassName() {
    return className;
}

public void setClassName(String className) {
    this.className = className;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getFathername() {
    return fathername;
}

public void setFathername(String fathername) {
    this.fathername = fathername;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getMothername() {
    return mothername;
}

public void setMothername(String mothername) {
    this.mothername = mothername;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getResidence() {
    return residence;
}

public void setResidence(String residence) {
    this.residence = residence;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

}
And This is main Activity for Student View..
public class ViewStudentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = ViewStudentActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<ModelViewStudent>datalist;
FirebaseFirestore db;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
StudentAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_student);


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    datalist=new ArrayList<>();
    adapter=new StudentAdapter(datalist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    fAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
    db.collection("Schools").document(user.getUid()).collection("Students").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list=queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                    for(DocumentSnapshot d:list){

                        ModelViewStudent obj=d.toObject(ModelViewStudent.class);
                        datalist.add(obj);
                    }
                    //Update Adapter

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu,menu);
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu);
    SearchView searchView= (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

}

In onSuccess(), add adapter = new StudentAdapter(datalist); before adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. Otherwise find a way to update backup after loaded data from Firestore.

You should add results.count = filtereddata.size() before you return results.
Please, also note that class studentViewHolder should be ststic class StudentViewHolder

@Vasia..thank you but didn't work after i added the same ..

@EccentricSoul, can you please add some logs to your code, to see where it stops and share the result?

As I am new to programming, so if you please suggest me blocks where i need to put logs? I have no idea where to put logs?

@EccentricSoul Sure! try adding one to onQueryTextChange to print newText, another one on the top of performFiltering to see keyword received, and 3rd one before return in performFiltering to see the result of filtering. Let me know what was the result

hey! I tried to addd some logs as you said..onQueryTextChange,keyword shows the chars which i press or del, same with newText and also with return the result is like this.....2021-01-19 09:29:24.931 D/StudentAdapter: android.widget.Filter$FilterResults@1fab8a7
2021-01-19 09:29:35.641 D/StudentAdapter: t
2021-01-19 09:29:35.641 D/StudentAdapter: android.widget.Filter$FilterResults@5de9d76
2021-01-19 09:29:46.070 D/StudentAdapter: tt
2021-01-19 09:29:46.070 D/StudentAdapter: android.widget.Filter$FilterResults@2915e50
2021-01-19 09:29:46.785 D/StudentAdapter: ttm
